# Should C++ attribute names be wrapped in double-underscores?

Tags: c++

To tell the compiler to exclude a function from the address sanitizer, the documentation for both [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) and [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#disabling-instrumentation-with-attribute-no-sanitize-address) say to use an `__attribute__` called `no_sanitize` like this:

```cpp
__attribute__((no_sanitize("address")))
void hidden_from_sanitizer();
```

But in the wild (e.g. Facebook's [folly library](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/CPortability.h#L83)), it seems this attribute is called `__no_sanitize__`:

```cpp
__attribute__((__no_sanitize__("address")))
void hidden_from_sanitizer();
```

GCC and Clang appear to accept both syntaxes, but which should I use? What's the difference? Is wrapping attribute names in double-underscores documented generally somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax) says:

> You may optionally specify attribute names with ‘__’ preceding and following the name. This allows you to use them in header files without being concerned about a possible macro of the same name. For example, you may use the attribute name `__noreturn__` instead of `noreturn`.

So you can use the double underscores if you want to be 100% safe in a library header file, or if you know of a name conflict with an existing macro.

Comment: Worth mentioning that C11 header `stdnoreturn.h` has `noreturn` macro which expands to `_Noreturn` and thus can collide with `__attribute__((noreturn))`, but not with `__attribute__((__noreturn__))`.

Comment: That's definitive for GCC. The closest thing I can find for clang is in their [`__has_attribute` documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#has-attribute). Search engines and underscores don't get along.

Answer (score 3):

These are compiler-specific attributes, not C++ language attributes, which [use a different syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), e.g. `[[noreturn]]`  or `[[maybe_unused]]`.

For compiler-specific features - you have to consult your compiler documentation, and there's no general rule.