# Clearing interrupt necessary inside an ISR? (for Atmega644p uC)

Tags: interrupt, interrupt-handling, atmega

When an interrupt service routine is being executed, is it necessary to clear global interrupts (using the cli(); command for example) to prevent another ISR from being executed or queued?

For example, if an external interrupt INT0 is being executed and while it is executing this same external interrupt were to be triggered again. Would that interrupt be queued to be executed after the first interrupt is finished?

would the follow code prevent an interrupt from being queued if it is executed during the current interrupt or would I need to clear an interrupt queue register?

```
ISR(someISR_vect){
  cli();
  some code...
  sei();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to do that manually. AVR hardware already disables interrupts for you and the compiler will not re-enable interrupts when your handler is executing (by default).

---

Quoting from the "Nested interrupts" section of [this page](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) (it has no anchors, CTRL + F "Nested"):

> The AVR hardware clears the global interrupt flag in SREG before entering an interrupt vector. Thus, normally interrupts will remain disabled inside the handler until the handler exits, where the RETI instruction (that is emitted by the compiler as part of the normal function epilogue for an interrupt handler) will eventually re-enable further interrupts.

The `ISR()` macro defines a function with a special name, and generates a call to that function in the interrupt table in AVR firmware. Additionally, the defined function might have [attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Function-Attributes.html) set. The two attributes which are of interest to you are `interrupt` and `signal`. Both declare the function as an interrupt handler, which causes the `return` statement to be replaced with a `reti` instruction (return from interrupt) and also cause the compiler to generate "function entry and exit sequences suitable for use in an interrupt handler".

The difference is that the `interrupt` automatically generates `sei` instruction which cause the interrupts to be *enabled* during the execution of your handler, basically overriding the hardware-set default. On the other hand, `signal` does not do that.

The only thing left to do is to check which one is set by `ISR()` by default. By consulting avr-libc code on github, specifically the [interrupt.h](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/blob/main/include/avr/interrupt.h#L134) file we can see that the `ISR()` macro specifies the `__signal__` attribute by default (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65872580/5457426) it's the same attribute). At the same time, the macro `ISR_BLOCK` which may be passed as an arg to `ISR()` is [blank](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/blob/main/include/avr/interrupt.h#L353). Meanwhile, the `interrupt` attribute is specified by the `ISR_NOBLOCK` macro [few lines below](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/blob/main/include/avr/interrupt.h#L356). According to this, the default attribute for your interrupt handlers is `signal`, which does not re-enable interrupts when your handler is executing. You may verify this by looking at a disassembly of your interrupt vector compiled with and without `ISR_NOBLOCK` set to see whether the `sei` instruction is generated.

---

As for the behaviour of interrupts while the global interrupt flag is disabled, i will refer to the manual of Atmega644p, which at current time i have found [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42744-ATmega644P_Datasheet.pdf) (it appears to be from 2016, but i doubt anything has changed since then in that regard):

> When using the CLI instruction to disable interrupts, the interrupts will be immediately disabled. No
> interrupt will be executed after the CLI instruction, even if it occurs simultaneously with the CLI instruction. (...) When using the SEI instruction to enable interrupts, the instruction following SEI will be executed before
> any pending interrupts, as shown in this example.

AVR does not have a way to queue interrupts while these are disabled. What happens is that once the interrupt happens, an interrupt-specific flag (in contrast to the *global* interrupt flag) is set. If the interrupts are disabled, the interrupt handler will *not* execute. This way an interrupt may be in a *pending* state as referred to in the quote above. An example would be a TOV (timer overflow) flag in the TC0 (timer0 control) register (found in section 16.9.8 in the manual). When the overflow happens in Timer0, the flag will be set to 1. If the interrupts are globally disabled, the interrupt handler will not run, but the flag will remain set. The interrupt will be in the pending state. If another interrupt of the same type (timer0 overflow) happens before the interrupt handler manages to run, it will be lost, as there is only one flag bit per interrupt type. On the other hand another interrupt type, which has a separate flag, might happen during that time. Since it has a separate interrupt bit flag, it will be not impacted by the timer0 overflow interrupt being in the pending state. It will also be put in the pending state (the flag will be set to 1 but no handler will run until the interrupts are enabled again).

This is true for flag-based interrupts. AFAIK there are a few interrupts in AVR which are not flag-based and which behave slightly differently, but i have no experience with those and do not want to spread misinformation about them. I'd assume it is still impossible to queue more than 1 of each in the pending state, though.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with AVR, but is it really true that interrupts arriving while the global interrupt flag is clear are just dropped?  Does that apply to all interrupts, or just the one being handled?    I'm having a hard time imagining how you could design any kind of reliable system if interrupts could randomly get lost like that.

Comment: `interrupt` does just `sei` but *not*  `cli` at any point. Same for `ISR_NOBLOCK` which is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I did get ahead of myself, thanks for noticing. I edited the `cli` parts out. @NateEldredge It is true, in reality one interrupt of each type may be in a pending state while the interrupts are globally disabled, but not more than one. If another interrupt of the same type happens when previous one is pending, it will be lost as there is only one flag bit per each interrupt type. I have added explanation to my answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cli` in an ISR is unnecessary because the AVR automatically disables interrupts when entering the ISR.

Using `sei` in an interrupt is actually pretty dangerous in theory.  It allows other interrupts to run before your interrupt has finished and deallocated the stack space it is using.  Therefore, you could have many nested interrupts running at the same time without limit, potentially filling up your stack.

To answer your other questions: using `cli` and `sei` just affects the global interrupt enable bit.  An interrupt flag from a peripheral can still be 1 or get changed to 1 regardless of the state of that bit.  The AVR will jump to its interrupt service routine the next time interrupts are globally enabled and the peripheral's interrupt flag is equal to 1.